# calculate new x509 subject hash for value for openssl

Tags: hash, openssl, new-operator, x509, csr

How to calculate 8 character hash of new openssl subject hash
Old hash method is just take from first 4 binary character (8 char in hex form) of md5 subject hash and reverse it like:

```
b373df0b7e7d063966ae886f3a88dbc5 = 0bdf73b3

=>b373df0b7e7d063966ae886f3a88dbc5
=>b373df0b
=>0bdf73b3
```

but new hash method is so different.
i tried from sha1 until sha512, but i can't get any similar string combination of openssl new hash.
looking for documentation at openssl but nothing found there.
any method or documentation for calculate it?
Edit:
Some people ask similar question. But I'm not familiar with java c++ or .net.
I'm familiar with php or JavaScript.
It's not about programming language, but about algorithm and calculation.

Comment: here you go [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237167/the-new-subject-hash-openssl-algorithm-differs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The new subject hash openssl algorithm differs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237167/the-new-subject-hash-openssl-algorithm-differs)

Comment: I'm not familiar with java. So can't understand what those script do.

Comment: To get the same signature you got in openssl you need to use the same hashing algorithm